# Best Practice for Hiding/Showing Multiple Divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have some divs which I want to allow users to switch between. I would write functions like this:

```
show_A = function () {$('.a').show(); $('.b').hide(); $('.c').hide();}
show_B = function () {$('.a').hide(); $('.b').show(); $('.c').hide();}
show_C = function () {$('.a').hide(); $('.b').hide(); $('.c').show();}
```

Then attach these functions to links or whatever. What's the best practice for abstracting out this sort of behavior? The total amount of code grows at N^2 with the number of divs, which is no good.

Answer (score 2):

Give all those divs that you want to hide a common class name and then show one of those. like:

html:

```
<div class="a toggle">a div</div>
<div class="b toggle">b div</div>
<div class="c toggle">c div</div>
```

Now the js:

```
show_A = function () {$('.toggle').hide(); $('.a').show();}
show_B = function () {$('.toggle').hide(); $('.b').show();}
show_C = function () {$('.toggle').hide(); $('.c').show();}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I've handled this is before was just to hide them all then show the one (or ones) that you want visible.

Something like...

```
var showSingleDiv = function(klass) {
    $('.container > div').hide();
    $(klass).show();
};
```

Granted you don't want to hide *every* `div` so you'll need to setup whatever `.container` is with your own markup.

Answer (score 0):

For each click, you could hide all the divs and then show only the one you need.

You could use a class to tag the divs involved...

```
<div id="a" class="collapse">...</div>
<div id="b" class="collapse">...</div>
<div id="c" class="collapse">...</div>
```

And use:

```
$(".collapse").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like, by adding a common class to all those elements:

```
<div class="toggle">a</div>
<div class="toggle">b</div>
<div class="toggle">c</div>

$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.toggle:visible').hide();    //Hide all visible 'toggle' div's
    $(this).show();                 //Show the clicked div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not()` selector.

```
show_A = function () {$('.a').show(); $('div:not(.a)').hide();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but it seems like what he's wanting is something along these lines:

```
$('div').each().click( function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('class');
    if( $("div[class*='"+cls+"']").is(':visible')){ $("div[class*='"+cls+"']").hide();}//
    else{ $("div[class*='"+cls+"']").show(); }
}
);
```

//Disclaimer - I did not check to see if the concatenated selector works, but adapted it from a reputable blog.